# Tunneling for remote access

Tags: tunnel, teamviewer

Most of the TCP/UDP ports are blocked within my campus network. I've argued this issue with IT department but I've got nothing. I need to access my computer at university when I'm at home. Is there a way to tunnel TeamViewer or by-pass this limitation?

Comment: What OS are you using (on both computers)? Do you have access from your university computer to outside? is it limited to only browsing web pages? Are you able to install new software on your computers or did the IT department limit your privileges?

Comment: I use Windows 7 Professional on both computers. There is no restriction to install software. IT does not control our computers in the lab. To my knowledge, I have no direct access to outside from my computer.

Comment: If teamviewer is locked out, other similar software would be blocked as well. You could try to install a ssh daemon on your home listening to port 443 do a tunnel inside and hope that would work. Nevertheless, if that somehow raises an alert, your IT department would lock you out completelly or raise a complaint (or worse) arguing you have incurred on serious breach of security compromising the whole campus' infrastructure...

Comment: I think that would not work since there should be a forwarding mechanism on the campus router into my computer at campus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of possibly violating your University acceptable use agreement, and security arrangement that they have obviously setup....I would STRONGLY advise working with the University IT department instead of trying to use tools to violate their restrictions.  Your violations could have legal consequences so I advise caution.

Answer (score 0):

I use LogMeIn, it uses HTTP ports for remote access. Give it a try at logmein.com.

Answer (score 0):

Tools like LogMeIn would work, but if that is blocked, you could also try creating an [SSH tunnel](http://www.revsys.com/writings/quicktips/ssh-tunnel.html) as long as you have a SSH server running on the remote system you are trying to connect to, as well as having a port open for SSH.